# TypeScript + Express: Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

In my `src/app.ts`, I have:

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: (req, res, buf) => req.rawBody = buf }))
```

But I get the error `Property 'rawBody' does not exist on type 'IncomingMessage'` on:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: (req, res, buf) => req.rawBody = buf }))
```

I have a `typings/express.d.ts`, in which I have:

```
declare namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
        rawBody: any;
    }
}
```

and my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./built",
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node"
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ],
    "files": [
        "typings/*"
    ]
}
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two issues here:

#### 1. `tsconfig.json`

The `files` option in `tsconfig.json` doesn't support wildcards like `typings/*`, only explicit filenames.

You can either specify the full path:

```
"files": [
    "typings/express.d.ts"
]
```

Or add the wildcard path to `include`:

```
"include": [
    "./src/**/*",
    "typings/*"
]
```

#### 2. Wrong Type

The error message mentions the type `IncomingMessage`, however you are augmenting the `Request` interface instead. Take a look at the type definitions for `body-parser` (parts omitted):

```js
import * as http from 'http';

// ...

interface Options {
    inflate?: boolean;
    limit?: number | string;
    type?: string | string[] | ((req: http.IncomingMessage) => any);
    verify?(req: http.IncomingMessage, res: http.ServerResponse, buf: Buffer, encoding: string): void;
}
```

The first argument of `verify` has the type `http.IncomingMessage` from the `'http'` module that's included with Node.js.

To augment the correct type, you'll want to change your `.d.ts` file to this:

```js
declare module 'http' {
    interface IncomingMessage {
        rawBody: any;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I use req downstream, it’ll be an Express request. So really, I want to augment both, no?

Comment: @Shamoon I suppose so, yes.